# Moved code into a function. Now doesn't work. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

First a huge code block followed by the actual question.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // debug. takes an object as argument and prints its content
    function printObject(o) {
    var out = '';
    // for (var p in o) {
    //     out += p + ': ' + o[p] + '\n';
    // }
    for (var p in o) {
        if (!o.hasOwnProperty(p)) out += '(inherited) ';
        out += p + ': ' + o[p] + '\n';
    }
    alert(out);
    }

    function makeDialogTable(users) {
    var result = '<table>\n<tr><td>Initials</td><td>Full Name</td></tr>\n';
    $.each(users, function(index, value) {
            result += '<tr><td>' + index + '</td><td>' + value + '</td></tr>\n';
    });
    result += '</table>';
    return (result);
    }


    function sendData(is_okay) {

    // if all form fields have been filled out
    if (is_okay == 1) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/cgi-bin/ajax.pl",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            // generate and send parameters to server-side script
        data: $(this).serialize(),

        // script call was *not* successful
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            $('div#create_result').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ", textStatus: " + textStatus + ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);


            $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
        }, // error 

        // script call was successful 
        // result contains the JSON values returned by the Perl script 
        success: function(result){
            if (result.error) { // script returned error
            $('div#create_result').text("result.error: " + result.error);
            $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
            } else { // perl script says everything is okay
            $('div#create_result').text("result.success: " + result.success + ", result.id: " + result.id);
            $('div#create_result').addClass("success");
            } //else
        } // success
        }); // ajax

    } else { // if (is_okay) { ...
        $('div#create_result').text("Submission cancelled. Changes have not been saved.");
        $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
    } // if/else
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // required for $(this) to work for save bottons
    $('form').live('submit', function(){

    var title      = this.elements.title.value;
    var owner      = this.elements.owner.value;
    var users      = this.elements.users.value;
    var groups     = this.elements.groups.value;
    var begin_date = this.elements.from.value;
    var end_date   = this.elements.to.value;
    var anchor     = this.elements.anchor.value;

    // get selected radio button using name instead if ID
    var type = $(this).find('input:radio[name="ctype"]:checked').val() || '';


    // check value
    var is_okay = 0;

    if (title == '') {
        alert('Title is required');
    } else if (!(/[A-Za-z0-9]|\s/.test(title))) {
        alert('Illegal characters in title. Only a-z A-Z and space is allowed');

    } else if (owner == '') {
        alert('Owner is required');
    } else if (!(/[A-Za-z]|,/.test(owner))) {
        alert('Illegal characters in owner. Only a-z A-Z and , is allowed');

    } else if (begin_date == '') {
        alert('Begin Date is required');
    } else if (!(/\d{2}\/\d{2}-\d{4}/.test(begin_date))) {
        alert('Illegal characters in Begin Date. Format must be: dd/mm-yyyy');

    } else if (end_date == '') {
        alert('End Date is required');
    } else if (!(/\d{2}\/\d{2}-\d{4}/.test(end_date))) {
        alert('Illegal characters in End Date. Format must be: dd/mm-yyyy');

    } else if (type == '') {
        alert('Type is required');

    } else if (type == "individuel" && groups != '') {
        alert('Groups are not allowed for individuel');
    } else if (type == "individuel" && users == '') {
        alert('Users is required');
    } else if (type == "individuel" && groups == '' && !(/[A-Za-z]|,/.test(users))) {
        alert('Illegal characters in users. Only a-z A-Z and , is allowed');

    } else if (type == "course" && users != '') {
        alert('Users are not allowed for course');

    } else if (type == "course" && groups == '') {
        alert('Groups is required');

    } else if (type == "course" && users == '' && !(/[A-Za-z]|,/.test(groups))) {
        alert('Illegal characters in groups. Only a-z A-Z and , is allowed');

    } else {
        is_okay = 1;
    }


    // if all form fields have been filled out
    // send the form data for varification and look up display names and show in a confirm box
    if (is_okay == 1) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/cgi-bin/ajax_confirm.pl",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            // generate and send parameters to server-side script
        data: $(this).serialize(),

        // script call was *not* successful
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            $('div#create_result').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText +
                        ", textStatus: " + textStatus +
                        ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
            $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
            alert("Error occured in ajax.js confirm code. Report this to mj@imm.dtu.dk");

        }, // error 

        // script call was successful 
        // result contains the JSON values returned by the Perl script 
        success: function(result){
            if (result.error) { // script returned error
            $('div#create_result').text("result.error: " + result.error);
            $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
            } else { // perl script says everything is okay

            // decode JSON string into arrays
            var users  = $.parseJSON(result.users);
            var owners = $.parseJSON(result.owners);


            // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
            $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 600,
                modal: true,
                open: function() {
                $(this).children('div.dialog-text').replaceWith("<h3><b>Users</b></h3>" + makeDialogTable(users) + "<h3><b>Owners</b></h3>" + makeDialogTable(owners));
                },

                buttons: {
                Okay: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    sendData(1);
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    is_okay = 0;
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    sendData(0);
                }
                } // buttons
            }); // dialog


            } //else
        } // success
        }); // ajax

    } else { // if (is_okay) { ...
        $('div#create_result').text("Fill out the form to create an activity");
        $('div#create_result').addClass("error");

        is_okay = 0;

    } // else


//  // if all form fields have been filled out
//  if (is_okay == 1) {

//      $.ajax({
//          type: "GET",
//          url: "/cgi-bin/ajax.pl",
//          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
//          dataType: "json",

//          // generate and send parameters to server-side script
//      data: $(this).serialize(),

//      // script call was *not* successful
//      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
//          $('div#create_result').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ", textStatus: " + textStatus + ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);

//          // extract error message
// //           var pattern = new RegExp(": \"(.+)\"}");
// //           var match = pattern.exec(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);    
// //           $('div#create_result').text(match[1]);

//          $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
//      }, // error 

//      // script call was successful 
//      // result contains the JSON values returned by the Perl script 
//      success: function(result){
//          if (result.error) { // script returned error
//          $('div#create_result').text("result.error: " + result.error);
//          $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
//          } else { // perl script says everything is okay
//          $('div#create_result').text("result.success: " + result.success + ", result.id: " + result.id);
//          $('div#create_result').addClass("success");
//          } //else
//      } // success
//      }); // ajax

//  } else { // if (is_okay) { ...
//      $('div#create_result').text("Fill out the form to create an activity");
//      $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
//  } // else

    $('div#create_result').fadeIn();
    return false;
    });
});
```

The same code can be read at

http://pastebin.com/0kXzZGND

with line numbers.

I moved the huge code block from line 205-245 into a function `sendData(is_okay)` at line 26-65. The function is called at line 181 and 186.

The code that I put in the function uses things like `$.ajax({` and `$(this).`.

Could this be a problem?

If so, how can that be fixed?

**Update**
The code block should update the HTML, but it doesn't do that anymore.

**Update**
After applying one patrick dw's solutions I get this error:

```
result is null
```

and it points to this code

```
success: function(result) {
```

in the newly created function.

Is it because the GET request now doesn't return anything?

Comment: Put the code related to your question *in the actual question*. There's no need for an external paste site, StackOverflow's own system formats code just fine. Pastebin isn't even a live site (and even live sites like jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com are just an *adjunct* to a question, the code should always be on SO itself).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: To be fair, it's a lot of code.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: That's fine. The point is that SO is more than just a resource for this person right now; it's meant to be a resource for others having a similar problem in the future. External links can get modified in an untracked way, moved, deleted, etc., making the question completely useless.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you tried `console.log()` inside those functions to see if they're actually being called. Please clarify what the issue really is.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I see your point, perhaps the question can be better presented more generically, by removing specific line numbers. Or perhaps edited when it's answered so we'll know what the relevant code is.

Comment: I agree with @T.J Crowder. It's important to include the code (as OP has now done). Though the line numbers are nice in pastebin.

Comment: I'd like to see line numbers on SO, but it's not like it's hard to put markers in the code. @Sandra: Best to ask first so people know what they're looking at (a lot of people won't even look past the code block otherwise), then quote your code (with markers).

Comment: @gAMBOOKa : yes, they get called. Now after applying the suggested answer, I get `result is null` in the newly created function. Are there ways to debug this?

Comment: @Sandra: So it looks like your perl script is not returning anything. Try declaring sample data in your perl script and run it manually to see if you get the desired results. Also, have you tried using Chrome's Inspector or Firebug for debugging. It might be that the path to the script is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is like with `$(this).`. If you're just calling a function like normal, the value of `this` will be `window`. I'm guessing you're expecting a DOM element.

You can manually set the value of `this` in the function you're calling by using the `.call` method.

To do so, call your function as follows:

```
sendData.call( this, 1 );
```

Another option would be to have your function accept another argument, and use that:

```
sendData( 1, this );

function sendData(is_okay, el) {

   // ...
   data: $(el).serialize(),
```

Comment: just clarifying, `.call(thisArg, normalArgs)`. `thisArg` will change the value of `this` within sendData to whatever is specified.

Comment: I have applied your second solution, and updated the question. I get the `result is null` now.